# Check whether both of the multiselect dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am creating two dropsdowns like this

```
var drp_nt = $('<select />', {
                               'id'     : 'drp_' + nt,
                               'name'   : 'drp_' + nt+'[]',
                               on: {
                                        change: check_data
                                        },
                               'multiple': true});

var drp_cnt = $('<select />', {
                              'id'     : 'drp_' + cnt,
                              'name'   : 'drp_' + cnt+'[]',
                              on: {
                                        change: check_data
                                        },
                              'multiple': true});
```

Now i am defining the check_data_function like this

```
function check_data()
{
    if($("select option:selected").length==2)
        alert('Two Dropdown Selected');
    else
        alert($("select option:selected").length);
}
```

I want to enable a button when both of the dropdown has some of the options selected.

in the above fragment of the code, the problem is, if i select `2` options from dropdown `drp_nt`, and select no option from `drp_cnt`, then also the alert `'Two Dropdown Selected'` is taking place.

I want to have the alert `'Two Dropdown Selected'` take place when both of the dropdowns will have some options selected. If one is having something selected while the other one don't, then the alert `'Two Dropdown Selected'` won't take place

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
function check_data() {
    if ($('select option:selected').parent().length == 2) {
        alert('Two Dropdown Selected');
    }
}
```

The idea is that you still select selected options, but then you get their parent `select` elements and verify that there are exactly two of them.

Check the demo below.

```js
$('select').change(check_data);

function check_data() {
    if ($('select option:selected').parent().length == 2) {
        alert('Two Dropdown Selected');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
    <option>Text 1</option>
    <option>Text 2</option>
    <option>Text 3</option>
    <option>Text 4</option>
</select>

<select multiple>
    <option>Text 1</option>
    <option>Text 2</option>
    <option>Text 3</option>
    <option>Text 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @MilindAnantwar.... this answer is the best one... I wont mind if one one options is selected from both.. I just want to have atleast one option be selected from each of the dropdowns

Comment: @MilindAnantwar.. no problem bro... atleast you tried... i will generously grant you one point for your effort...

Answer (score 1):

you are selecting both dropdown in jquery using select

**

```
function check_data()
{
    if($("select option:selected").length==2)
        alert('Two Dropdown Selected');
    else
        alert($("select option:selected").length);
}
```

**

$('select') will select both dropdown. So when you check in jquery, after you selected two in one drop down, this will give you result as two selected. So you need to check like following

```
    function check_data()
{
    if($("#id1 option:selected").length>1 && $("#id2 option:selected").length>1)
        alert('Two Dropdown Selected');
    else
        alert('select any one of the option from both dropdown');
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this ans will take lesser time than, finding parent(in marked as answer). Since it's jquery, it's not a big issue. There won't be much time difference. That's nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by filtering the list of selects so that you get only those with options selected and then check the length

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('change','select',function(){
      var selectsWithOptionsSelected = $('select').filter(function(){
          return $('option:selected',this).length>0;
      });
      alert(selectsWithOptionsSelected.length);
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select rows="3" multiple>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
<select rows=3 multiple>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

You may want to fiddle with the selectors to only target the `select` instances you're interested in, for example you could give them a class and use that in both selectors (`select.myClassName`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery().each`

```
function check_data()
{
  var counter = 0;
  jQuery('select').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).find('option:selected').length == 2) {
      counter++;
    }
  });
  if(counter == jQuery('select').length)
      alert('Two Dropdown Selected');
  else
      alert($("select option:selected").length);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative just for giggles:

```
function check_data() {
    $('select:has(option:selected)').length > 1 && alert('Foo');
}
```